# Google Maps in Shadowbox

Tags: google-maps, iframe, shadowbox

Is it possible to open the iframe from google maps in shadowbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for **Shadowbox** is at GitHub where the author has provided an [**Examples Folder**](https://github.com/mjijackson/shadowbox/tree/v3.0.3/examples).

There, you will find a [**google-maps.html**](https://github.com/mjijackson/shadowbox/blob/v3.0.3/examples/google-maps.html) file demonstrating how to open a **Google Map** in Shadowbox.

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8LWq/)